# hadoop job to split xml files

Tags: hadoop

I've got 1000's of files to process.  Each file consists of 1000's of XML files concatenated  together.

I'd like to use Hadoop to split each XML file separately.  What would be a good way of doing this using Hadoop?

**NOTES:** I am total Hadoop newbie.  I plan on using Amazon EMR.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [Mahout's XmlInputFormat](http://people.apache.org/~isabel/mahout_site/mahout-examples/apidocs/org/apache/mahout/classifier/bayes/XmlInputFormat.html). It's a shame that this is in Mahout and not in the core distribution.

Are the XML files that are concatenated at least in the same format? If so, you set `START_TAG_KEY` and `END_TAG_KEY` to the root in each of your files. Each file will show up as one `Text` record in the `map`. Then, you can use your favorite Java XML parser to finish the job.